# Intellij not recognizing javax.mail imports but project is building fine

Tags: intellij-idea, jakarta-mail

I am using javax.mail library in my project. My project is building fine using - mvn clean install, but when i try to debug my Intellij IDE shows error and it is not able to recognize the javax.mail imports. I have restarted my IDE from FILE -> Invalidate Caches and restart,still no luck.

These are not getting recognized by intellij IDEA,stating unused imports. I am using below the depeendency versions as:- javax.activation - 1.1.1 and javax.mail - 1.4.

Because the project is building fine,i believe the problem lies in some IDE setting.Kindly let me know if this can be resolved.

[image]

Comment: The circle over your external libraries makes no sense, as it doesn't show any javax.mail there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope> <!-- add this only if code will run in a java container (i.e. tomcat, etc)-->
</dependency>
```

And you should also see the mail classes under External Libraries -> Maven:javax.mail:mail:1.4 -> mail-1.4.jar -> javax.mail

There are also newer versions of the java mail dependency you can use, like 1.4.7 or 1.5.0-b01

The latest version (as pointed out by @Mark Rotteveel) is 1.6.3 and the maven coordinates have changed to jakarta:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Based on your code I have created a simplified project version with only two files; pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>message-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and SendMail.java

```
package com.test;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SendMail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sendMail(new Exception("Problem with cable"));
    }

    public static void sendMail(Exception exception) {
        String to = "destination@test.com";
        String from = "sender@test.com";
        String host = "smtp.test.com";
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject("Trade-processor instance shutdown!");
            message.setText(getExceptionMessage(exception));
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getExceptionMessage(Exception e) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        return sw.toString();
    }
}
```

- Make sure your 'java' source folder is marked as source (right click on it and select 'Mark directory as -> sources root' if it is not already light blue)
- Make sure the class package (com.test) names match i.e. 'src/main/java/com/test/SendMail' on the project pane and 'package com.test' in SendMail.java

[image: IDEA Project showing package and External Libraries]

Comment: Latest version is 1.6.3, see: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/javamail/ And using provided scope is only correct if you are going to deploy to a JavaEE server that includes JavaMail.

Comment: I provided this
 <scope>provided</scope>
and it worked.Thanks !

Comment: @egallardo Now the code is not showing any errors,but when i try to debug,it is running into ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException,Is there any way to resolve this also?

Comment: @ZerekSees Remove the <scope>provided</scope> line. Sounds contradictory but it looks like the problem was somewhere else.